# Responsive menu button doesn't automaticly close

Tags: jquery, menu, responsive

I have some problems with my responsive menu on mobile. When I click on the menu-button it collapse a dropdown menu. But when I click on one of the links in the dropdown menu, it won't close by itself.

Can you please help me out?

Here's the link: http://www.air-technics.nl/warmtepomp

Comment: Give us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.navbar-nav > li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).find('>a').prop('hash');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 500);
    $("#menu-icon").trigger("click"); // click on the hamburger icon
});
```